# Making pages without images interesting

Tags: website-design, page-layout

I am currently designing a web application which, long story short, takes extracts data from an existing system and transforms it into posts which are sent out to employees. Basically, the existing system is not conducive to the reading of the data, and my application needs to display these posts in an engaging way so that employees actually read them.

The problem I am facing is that the existing system does capture any pictures and that I am a bit of a web design novice. What I have currently is a simple page which outputs the required information in blog format (headings with paragraph text), however this is really boring to look at.

My question for you is how do you ensure your pages are still engaging and interesting to look at when:
 1. There are no images available to use.
 2. The page has to be dynamically generated (so you can't make design choices on a page by page basis).

Comment: Are you able to you colours and shapes somehow?

Comment: Any wireframes/layout would help us understand the UI better and help provide better answers. Surely, you can use colors and shapes and some interesting typography right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a better fit in Graphic Design SE (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let your employees help you by becoming a social media:

- keep statistics of who is opening an article, display a counter by department
- add a *like* button or rating stars then identify most interesting articles
- let employees write keywords for articles they read. Use trends in those keywords to highlight new articles that have the same ones and suggest "Articles similar to those you read".
- propose a useful highlighter tool for employees to keep interesting quotes. Display those quotes in a nice way as an insert in a newspaper

This all helps employees judge which articles might interest them before opening them.

Answer (score 0):

I would worry less about trying to make the pages look "engaging" and focus on making them readable. The use of appropriate line lengths, line spacing, font size, etc., will make better posts than colors and shapes.